# Downloading songs and photos with webView on an iPhone

Tags: iphone, download

I want to download songs and photos with my iPhone from a website that offers them for free.

I’m using a webView for that instead of Safari.

I’m thinking about downloading the files, just like I download to my Nokia mobile.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you clarify you Use-Case a bit more? Do you want to browse the web via a webview and then attempt to download content by clicking on it? Or, are you just looking to download content from the web using the buit-in iOS networking APIs?

Comment: Are you creating a site, or do you just mean as a user? If it's the latter, Stack Overflow is for programming questions, and you should ask this on superuser.com or someplace devoted to iPhone usage.

Comment: i want to download it by my own application

Comment: Sorry, I guess I didn't understand the question.

Comment: @Alex JL--No worries man...... please try again if possible...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Download and play mp3 file from url with iphone application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651362/download-and-play-mp3-file-from-url-with-iphone-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NSURLConnection to download the file without using a webview.

The connection will send you the downloaded data by chunk via the following delegate method:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
```

When finished, the following will get called:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```

and then you can save the corresponding NSData to wherever you decided.

Alternatively, look at the excellent ASIHttp package:

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/